# I want to use a thin gauge wire from a Nema 14-50 outlet

Tags: circuit-breaker, 240v, nema

I have an RV and want to plug into the typical Nema 14-50 outlet found at campsites. However, I am never going to draw more than say 15amps. I would rather not have a heavy bulk cable that will never come close to its capacity.

In addition, it will be connected to an inverter that only takes 240V. It does not use the neutral. Therefore, I would like to use a 3 conductor 14gauge wire.

Clearly this would be bad if there was a short somewhere down stream of the outlet. The wire would get overloaded and burn. **I am wondering if there are any in-line or outlet pluggable circuit breakers or fuses that can make this safe?**

The idea would be to have a 15amp circuit breaker or fuse in the plug of the cord.
Or a Nema 14-50P to Nema 6-15R converter, which would necessarily have some circuit breaker or fuse internal to it.

EDIT: I just found there are 14-50P to 6-15R adapters, but shouldn't there be some sort of fuse in this?

I'm not finding this to purchase, but maybe there is a different name?

Is this something one could build? I am not finding parts to do it easily. It would need to be somewhat water resistant.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/AC-WORKS-220-Volt-120-Volt-Household/dp/B07WRSXKN2/

Comment: That's a 5-15, not a 6-15 adapter.

Comment: Right, it's doing 240 -> 120, but I want 240V out. But there seems to be a fuse or breaker in it which is half the issue.

Comment: There is no reason you need a neutral wire if all of your loads are 240 volt.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find an actual listed (UL, ETL, etc. - not CE, that's not a listing) 6-15 adapter with a fuse (or breaker, but a fuse is more likely in an adapter) that would work.

You could build something using a weatherproof sub-panel connected to a short cord of proper gauge connected to a NEMA 14-50 plug, with a 15A 2-pole breaker connected to a NEMA 6-15 receptacle in a weatherproof box. You'll need some sort of portable stand to hold the parts upright.

That collection of parts will probably cost more than a suitable cord for the NEMA 14-50 to your RV, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found it.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0BRJHLHZT/ref=sw_img_1?smid=A1FMORBC3WJU92&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BRJHLHZT)

I failed to find the solution before I posted, because I didn't properly research the Nema plug types to determine what I was looking for.

In addition I was not expecting it was possible to find the adapters that allow one to drop down the wire gauge without a proper fusing/breaking.

Comment: Hi John  the link can disappear making your answer useless. If you add a photo from amazon and leave the link in, it would be so much better.

Comment: Just note that the photos in that link show no actual UL listing, just some claim that it would conform (i.e. claim by manufacturer not independently certified). This is pretty typical of the made-up-brand-name imported products.

Comment: There are potential issues with this plan. You won't have a neutral if you are only using a 3-pin connection.